# Add an answer that doesn't directly answer the question?

Tags: discussion, comments, reputation, not-an-answer

I have seen many questions recently, with different mistakes, than the question was about.

An example:

there was a man, looking for bugs in his code, that caused an exception. I didn't know, what raised the exception, but I found an sql injection there.

How should I warn him? I think, this should be written into a comment, unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation for commenting. Should I post, what I found, as an answer, although it isn't an answer, or should I just ignore it?

Comment: Solution: suggest 9 more edits to get to the 50 reputation and then comment.  Answers must answer the actual question.  Any additional improvements are welcome additions, but answers should always answer the question.

Comment: just bite your tongue and move on, until you earn the rep required.

Comment: For this time I solved it. I found a right answer to the question and appended my warning with "also note that...". But it haven't solved the basic problem yet. It just moved it to later time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The answer box should never be used for comments.**

The restriction on comments is there to deter spammers and comments like "Thank you", "Me too", "I have another question" etc. For users that are serious about using the site, it is relatively easy to get past.

You gain rep when your questions or answers are upvoted or accepted, you accept answers to your questions, or you suggest edits. You only have 18 more rep to gain before you can post a comment, which you can achieve through:

- One answer upvote and an accept
- Four question upvotes
- Nine suggested edits

or any combination thereof.

---

**Note:** If you are going to suggest edits, please make sure that you fix all of the problems that you observe, not just one or two things that may be wrong with the post.

> **Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged** - try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you observe.
>   <sub>[From the help center page on the editing privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)</sub>